# How to export file after use XSLT to transfer to data?

Tags: magento2

I tried to export. But it's not working?

I checked https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-import-xslt-transformation-how-to-import-any-xml-to-magento-2.html but not succeded.

Comment: https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-import-xslt-transformation-how-to-import-any-xml-to-magento-2.html This will help you.

Comment: i tried it but failed

Comment: Can you please elaborate more ? The steps you followed and the customization you have done to achieve this ?